# Bot Framework Web Chat Token Protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, botframework

I'm building a chatbot for fun and I cannot send messages to the following API: https://webchat.botframework.com/api/conversations.

After a webchat user send a message, I know the conversation Id and Sender ID. In order to reply, I do the following steps:

First, I retrieve the token with the following code:

```
response = requests.post(
    "https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens/conversation",
    headers={"Authorization": "BotConnector  " + pwdChat,"Content-Type": "application/json"})
data = response.json()
token = data
```

Then, I would like to send a message to the webchat user with he following code:

```
requests.post('https://webchat.botframework.com/api/conversations/' + sendersk2 + '/messages/',
          headers={"Authorization": "Botconnector " + token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
          json={
                "type": "message",
                "text": "Hi!"
          })
```

But, I receive an Response [403] error labelled as : "BadArgument:Security token not valid for this conversation"

Any idea of the issue?

Comment: The link you've posted is a 404 error.

Comment: So, are you trying to do is to talk with your BOT from a custom client (in this case a python-based client?

Comment: I try to SEND messages from my python based BOT to the webchat botframework. That's it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that might help.

1. The endpoint you're using brings back a complex JSON object and you'll need to extract the `token` property from that.
2. Alternatively, you can use `https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens` instead, but you'll also need to trim quotes off the end.

Basically, look at the response from your token POST request and ensure you're pulling the token out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally it looks like you are talking to the V1 endpoints. We no longer actively support V1. Please consider [upgrading to V3](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/upgrade-to-v3/#navtitle). Thanks.